Why the T1 recovery & T2 decay are independent?
I was thinking that the decrease in transverse magnetization results in the recovery of longitudinal magnetization.
However, recently, I found it was wrong. I saw a diagram

and also saw many writings saying "T1 and T2 relaxation are independent."
How is it possible? Where does the power emitted(?) from T2 decay go to?
(and also, all the animations I saw expressed them as dependent on each other.)

T2 decay is caused by the decohherence of spins and does not require any sort of energy transfer (the spins alignment with respect to the B0 filed does not change and spins remain in transverse plane,they only decohere relative to each other. As a result, the total transverse magnetization which is sum of their transverse dipole vector becomes smaller up to a point where they cancel each other out). T1 is the rate of equilibrium restoration where the magnetization restore to its equilibrium value along B0. This process requires energy trasnfer, but this energy transfer occurs between the spins and their neighboring atoms, not RF Coils. The RF coils do not act as antennas, they only provide some sort of magnetic coupling.
